# isPerformingAutoCompletion always false?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, textwatcher

I have implemented a TextWatcher on my AutoCompletionTextView and I am trying to work with the isPerformingAutoCompletion method as a means to check if AutoCompletion successful (i.e. a match exists).

But it seems the isPerformingAutoCompletion always returns false even though autoCompletion has potential matches?

I'm using a simple array adapter with ACTV:

```
private void initQuickSelect()
    quickSelectAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Items );
    acTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actv_view);
    acTextView.setAdapter(quickSelectAdapter);
}
```

and my TextWatcher:

```
 private void setupTextListener(){
    acTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(s.length() > 0){
                Log.d("gw", String.valueOf(acTextView.isPerformingCompletion()));

            }

        }
    });
}
```

the debug log always returns false, any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: what is your goal anyway? what do you want to achieve? see [here](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.java#919) for more info and ^F `mBlockCompletion`

Comment: I has trying to add a hook to tell me exactly when the autocomplete ran out of auto complete options.

Comment: ok, what is your data model for your ACTV? where is data taken from?

Comment: I'm using a standard array adapter see my fist code snippet above,  for this I'm passing it a string arraylist. I have tried all sorts of checks within the textwatcher, my problem is that textwatcher fetches the adapter data before adapter updates therefore using any adapter functions like getCount are always lagging ghe actual view if that makes sense?

Comment: why do you need those checks in `TextWatcher`? and why do you need `TextWatcher` at all?

Comment: The app allows the user to search for an item using the actv, as the user types a dropdown of items appears narrowing as the type more, they can tap to select an item from dropdown however if the type an item not on list (predetermined list fed as arraylist) I want a button to highlight at right of actv which if tapped will allow user to save as new item. This will then add to the predetermined list for next time.

Comment: maybe you should look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830)

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look now, appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isPerformingCompletion` will return true to the watcher when the user selects one of the items offered as a completion.

It sounds like you're expecting it to return true when there *are* valid completions being offered. I'm not sure how to find that information.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense, I thought this returned true as long as there were valid auto complete outputs and false when the i.e. drop-down went empty.